# selenium python can't detect id nor name

Tags: python, selenium

I tried to access a website whit selenium but python cant find the id nor the name.
Here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='D:\code\geckodriver.exe')
browser.get('http://admin.chhs.edu.my/schooladmin/jw/login.php')
assert "教务系统" in browser.title

def login():
    elem = browser.find_element_by_name('txtUserName')
    elem.send_keys('sportday')
    elem = browser.find_element_by_name('txtPassWord')
    elem.send_keys('xxxxxx')
    elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

def search():
    elem2 = browser.find_element_by_name('txtFind')
    elem2.send_keys('14066')
    elem2.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

login()
search()
```

And the html of the website I am accessing:

```
<form name="search" method="post" action="http://admin.chhs.edu.my/schooladmin/jw/index.php">
  <input name="txtFind" id="txtFind" type="text">
  <input name="button" id="button" value="搜寻" type="submit">
</form>
```

**NOTE** the password isn't correct due to some privacy problems.

**BTW this thread have been solved, thank you everyone**

Comment: Are you sure that the elements are loaded by the time you call search()? If they are not, then Selenium will not be able to find them. Try waiting for a few seconds with time.sleep after you login. If it is successful after that, then you'll know the issue is that the elements haven't finished loading yet.

Comment: Please add the error. Most probably this is due to page elements not being on DOM by the time your functions execute. Please see the answer added below and add some wait. Your script works fine on my system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this code :

```
def search():
    elem2 = browser.find_element_by_name('txtFind')
    elem2.send_keys('14066')
    elem2.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

To this :

```
def search():
    elem2 = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "txtFind")))
    elem2.send_keys('14066')
    elem2.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Note that if **ID** is given , then there is no need to go for any locator.

Answer (score 0):

You've only posted some of the html. One option is that the locators for the login aren't valid. The other option is that the program begins looking for the elements before the page is loaded. In this case the exception would state that the element was not found.

I had a similar issue and what worked for me was to place an `explicit wait` on the first element I would be searching for in the new page. An explicit wait waits a specified amount of time for a specified condition to be met.

For example:
`element = WebDriverWait(driver, seconds).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.NAME, 'txtuserame'))`

Alternatively you can use an `implicit wait` which ideally causes the driver to wait a specified amount of time **if** the page hasn't loaded. In my experience it's very dependent on the website and it often doesn't work as intended.

An example of an implicit wait in python would be `driver.implicitly_wait(10)`
Implicit wait relates to the driver rather than the element, and remain in effect for the lifespan of the driver instance.

You can find more info about wait over [here](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits) and you can find a list of `expected conditions` that you can use with `explicit wait` [here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html).

Answer (score 0):

To send a character sequence to the *Search* field you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

  browser=webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\GeckoDriver\geckodriver-v0.20.1-win64\geckodriver.exe')
  browser.get('http://admin.chhs.edu.my/schooladmin/jw/login.php')
  assert "教务系统" in browser.title

  def login():
      elem = browser.find_element_by_name('txtUserName')
      elem.send_keys('sportday')
      elem = browser.find_element_by_name('txtPassWord')
      elem.send_keys('123456')
      elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

  def search():
      elem2 = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#txtFind")))
      elem2.send_keys('14066')
      elem2.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

  login()
  search()
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: search_result]